# How to use timestamp column for filtering records in where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Query :

```
SELECT event_time, user_host, argument 
FROM mysql.general_log 
WHERE event_time > ('2016-08-04 10:50:27') 
AND user_host LIKE 'vareity_1_1%' 
OR user_host LIKE 'db_tvm%'
```

[image]

The query is working but am records which doesn't satisfy the where clause.
Here in the image you can see the results got

Answer (score 1):

`AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. Your query, without parentheses, is equivalent to this:

```
SELECT event_time, user_host, argument 
FROM mysql.general_log 
WHERE (event_time > '2016-08-04 10:50:27' AND user_host LIKE 'vareity_1_1%')
   OR user_host LIKE 'db_tvm%' ;
```

Try this instead:

```
SELECT event_time, user_host, argument 
FROM mysql.general_log 
WHERE event_time > '2016-08-04 10:50:27' 
 AND (user_host LIKE 'vareity_1_1%' OR user_host LIKE 'db_tvm%') ;
```